# Why doesn't this XPlot.Plotly code compile>

Tags: charts, f#, plotly

I found the code below in this URL:

https://tahahachana.github.io/XPlot/chart/plotly-box-plots.html

```
let trace1 = Box(y = y0)
let trace2 = Box(y = y1)

Figure(Data.From [trace1; trace2])
```

I installed `XPlot.Plotly` and `FSharp.Data` and added these three lines above the code:

```
open System
open FSharp.Data
open XPlot.Plotly
```

Still the code does not compile as `Data` and `Figure` are not recognized even though the `Intellisense` in the URL shows them as `Xplot.Plotly.Data` and `Xplot.Plotly.Figure`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the documentation needs to be updated - if you can send a pull request with a fix, that would be fantastic. I got XPlot to show two boxplots using this:

```
let y0 = [1.; 2.; 3.; 4.; 5.]
let y1 = [6.; 7.; 8.; 9.; 5.]

let trace1 = Box(y = y0)
let trace2 = Box(y = y1)

Chart.Plot [trace1; trace2]
```

Comment: Many thanks. I would love to send a pull request but that is well over my head. I live in Rio de Janeiro and except for a young fellow I am teaching F# I do not know personally a living soul that programs in F#. Since I am not a programmer myself (I am an economist) my knowledge has many gaps.

Comment: @Soldalma Nice! I was talking at QCon Rio about F# a few years back! Getting started with contributing should be pretty easy - all you need to do is to fix the code in this file so that it produces the chart correctly: https://github.com/fslaborg/XPlot/blob/master/docsrc/content/chart/plotly-box-plots.fsx A good walkthrough on sending a PR is here: https://codeburst.io/a-step-by-step-guide-to-making-your-first-github-contribution-5302260a2940